# Порядок включения ресурсов в исполняемый файл в Delphi 7

Tags: delphi, pascal, delphi-7, resources, ресурсы

Всем доброго времени суток.

Не могу понять, в каком порядке компилятор Delphi 7 упаковывает ресурсы в исполняемый файл?

Использую классическую схему - из текстовых RC-файлов автоматически собираются и подключаются эквивалентные RES. На данный момент имею 3 ресурсных файла, которые подключаются в DPR файле проекта в следующем порядке:

```
{$R 'res\MAINICON.res' 'res\MAINICON.rc'}       // Главный значок программы в нескольких размерах
{$R 'res\VERSIONINFO.res' 'res\VERSIONINFO.rc'} // Информация о версии
{$R 'res\ICONS.res' 'res\ICONS.rc'}             // Остальные значки
```

MAINICON.rc:

```
MAINICON ICON res/image_capture_all_sizes.ico
```

ICONS.rc:

```
CAMERA_BW ICON res/camera_bw.ico
CAMERA_FLASH_1 ICON res/camera_flash1.ico
CAMERA_FLASH_2 ICON res/camera_flash2.ico
CAMERA_FLASH_3 ICON res/camera_flash3.ico
CAMERA_FLASH_4 ICON res/camera_flash4.ico
CAMERA_FLASH_5 ICON res/camera_flash5.ico
CAMERA_FLASH_6 ICON res/camera_flash6.ico
CAMERA_FLASH_7 ICON res/camera_flash7.ico
```

После компиляции вижу, что основным значком программы отображается не `MAINICON`, а `CAMERA_BW`.

Открыл EXE-шник программой PE Explorer и вижу, что порядок включения значков в разделе `Icon entry` получился следующий:

```
CAMERA_BW
MAINICON 48пкс.
MAINICON 32пкс.
MAINICON 24пкс.
MAINICON 16пкс.
CAMERA_FLASH_5
CAMERA_FLASH_6
CAMERA_FLASH_7
CAMERA_FLASH_1
CAMERA_FLASH_2
CAMERA_FLASH_3
CAMERA_FLASH_4
MAINICON 64пкс.
```

Порядок в `Group icon`:

```
CAMERA_BW
CAMERA_FLASH_1
CAMERA_FLASH_2
CAMERA_FLASH_3
CAMERA_FLASH_4
CAMERA_FLASH_5
CAMERA_FLASH_6
CAMERA_FLASH_7
MAINICON
```

Где-то вроде читал, что `MAINICON` всегда должен быть расположен первым. Но насколько я вижу, порядок включения в ресурсных файлах на реальное положение в исполняемом файле никак не влияет.

**P.S.:** Перейти на более свежую среду Delphi не предлагать.

Comment: Иконка приложения загружается по имени `FIcon.Handle := LoadIcon(MainInstance, 'MAINICON');`, порядок здесь не причем.

Comment: Ну так это если явно её вызывать по имени в коде, а тут Проводник Windows сам ищет данный ресурс и для всех размеров почему-то выбирает самый первый `CAMERA_BW`. Если оставить в ресурсах из значков только `MAINICON`, то всё в порядке.

Comment: Компилятор включает ресурсы в алфавитном порядке. А проводник Windows выбирает [первую](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/ms997538(v=msdn.10)?redirectedfrom=MSDN#choosing-an-icon) иконку по порядку. На имя `MAINICON` ему плевать.

Comment: Переименуйте MAINICON в 1ICON, например, и загружайте руками после Application.Initialize, например.